# name of these compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I'd call c. 6- (3 aminocyclohexyl- methylamino) cyclohexa-2,4-dien-1-one and d. 1r, 2s- 2 (2-formyl- 4-methoxycarbonyl-but-3-en-1yl) cyclobutanecarboxylic acid[image]

Comment: How do you see two amino groups in ***c***? What you call a "4-methoxycarbonyl-but-3-en-1yl" substituent actually is 5-methoxy-5-oxopent-3-en-1-yl.

Comment: You're right. In c it's 6- (3 hydroxycyclohexyl- methylamino) cyclohexa-2,4-dien-1-one. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you correctly labeled the second molecule's stereocenters?